# wordpress parent child page url structure

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site and there are 3 main pages and 3 sub pages in each main pages. like

Stories
    story1
    story2
    story3

When I click on Main menu the URL should be like `www.domain.com/{mainmanu}` (ie `www.domain.com/stories` and when I click on one sub page in this page, it should be like `www.domain.com/stories/story1`

I know I can have custom post type like `%category%/%post_name%`. But here 
these are pages (not posts)

How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set the parent property in Page Attributes.  It is located on the right hand side of the page editor. For instance, for the Story 1 page, you need to set the parent to Stories.